# Passing a variable from VB Code behind to aspx front end page

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to hide a link based on a variable value (groupId) on the code behind file.
Below is what I tried based on various search results that I found on stack overlfow and else where.

Approach 1 :

```
<asp:HyperLink  ID="test_id" runat="server" 
         NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("report.aspx")%>' 
         Text='Report' ToolTip="Generate Report" 
         ForeColor="#333399" Font-Names="Tahoma" Target = "_blank"
         > 
        </asp:HyperLink>
```

Code behind:

```
Dim groupId As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("GROUP_ID")
            'bmt_id.
            If (groupId = 0) Then
                test_id.Visible=True;

            End If
```

Error : 'test_id' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Approach 2:

aspx page:

```
<%If {<%=groupId%>} = 0 Then%>

<asp:HyperLink  ID="test_id" runat="server" 
         NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("report.aspx")%>' 
         Text='Report' ToolTip="Generate Report" 
         ForeColor="#333399" Font-Names="Tahoma" Target = "_blank"
         > 
        </asp:HyperLink>

     <%End If%>
```

Error : groupId not found error, during run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your attempts are pretty close, but have a few flaws.

Approach 1 : You were using the wrong name for your hyperlink.  You named it ID="test_id".  Not "Hyperlink2".

```
<asp:HyperLink  ID="test_id" runat="server" 
     NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("report.aspx")%>' 
     Text='Report' ToolTip="Generate Report" 
     ForeColor="#333399" Font-Names="Tahoma" Target = "_blank"
> 
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Code behind:

```
Dim groupId As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("GROUP_ID")

If (groupId = 0) Then
    test_id.Visible=True
End If
```

Approach 2: You were using GroupId as a variable (private) instead of a public property.

aspx page:

```
<%If groupId = 0 Then%>

<asp:HyperLink  ID="test_id" runat="server" 
     NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("report.aspx")%>' 
     Text='Report' ToolTip="Generate Report" 
     ForeColor="#333399" Font-Names="Tahoma" Target = "_blank"
> 
</asp:HyperLink>

<%End If%>
```

Code behind:

```
Public Readonly Property groupId As String
    Get
        return ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("GROUP_ID")
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: No the Approach1 doesnot work. I edited my Approach1 in the post. It was a typo earlier. Sorry. To follow approach2, actually my ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("GROUP_ID") is in page_load method. How Do I handle that ? I saved it to a local variable in page_load method and using it back in the property method groupId. Is this the right apporoach for apporach2 ?

Comment: For approach 2, declare ds as a page level variable instead of declaring it within page_load.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Approach2 worked perfectly!!! Was just curious to know why the approach1 would not work.

Comment: I'm guessing that your *.aspx.designer.vb file does not contain a declaration for your control test_id.  Usually, when your control has runat="server" and codebehind says the control is not declared, that is the reason.  It can be tricky to fiddle-with it and fix it.  Approach 2 is just a little simpler.

Comment: One thing to consider: putting too much logic (even display-related logic) into your ASPX instead of the associated codebehind can quickly yield a completely unmaintainable application.  What you've got is pretty straight-forward - but it can be a slippery slope.  If you foresee needing to add more logic like this in the future, you will want to seriously consider moving all your logic into the codebehind - there's a lot of value in having everything in a single location.

Answer (score 1):

In code-behind you need to reference the ID, which is "test_id", not "Hyperlink2".

```
        If (groupId = 0) Then
            test_id.Visible=True

        End If
```

Comment: No. It doest not work . Sorry for my typo earlier.Changed my post now.